# FFMPEG Extract Front Centre Channel as an audio track

Tags: ffmpeg, tracks

I have an MKV video file with 5.1 channel audio. I want to use the third channel (FC) as AAC Audio Track 1 (with language label Malayalam), the whole audio file copied as Audio Track 2  (also with language label Malayalam), and save the video as MKV. I don't want to reencode the video.

How can I do that?

I tried this:

```
ffmpeg -i "input.mkv" -filter_complex "channelsplit=channel_layout=5.1[FL][FR][FC][LFE][BL][BR]" -map '[FC]' -acodec aac -map 0 -vcodec copy "output [Background Removed].mkv"
```

It gave me the error:

```
Filter channelsplit:BR has an unconnected output
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only extract the relevant channel using channelsplit.

Use

`ffmpeg -i "input.mkv" -filter_complex "channelsplit=channel_layout=5.1:channels=FC[FC]" -map '[FC]' -map 0 -c copy -c:a:0 aac "output [Background Removed].mkv"`

Comment: Thanks. I need at least 15 reputation to up-vote. Your answer is really useful. Please mention how to set the language of the new track to Malayalam, so that I can select this as the correct answer.

Comment: Add `-metadata:s:a:0 language=mal`

Comment: Up-voted and Selected, although it would be useful for everybody to describe each part of the command.